# PHP preg_prepare, shield vs sql injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I would like to ask a question about **preg_prepare**, if I use this instead of escaping chars and filters, is it safe in case of **sql injection** ?

Comment: I would say that the usage of prepared statements is the safest way to protect your application from sql injection.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897546/does-pg-prepare-prepared-statement-not-pdo-prevent-sql-injection